Is there any way to remove break line from the middle of str in cell to use it for HTMLBody
I made a action list file in excel and i'm trying to send notification mails to people by using the cell information. Some cells have line breaks (Alt+Enter) which makes impossible to use
....
For i = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
        ' Check if the Status column is not "Closed"
        If tbl.ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange(i).Value <> "Closed" And tbl.ListColumns("Task").DataBodyRange(i).Value <> "" Then
            Set emailItem = emailApplication.createItem(0)
            emailItem.BodyFormat = 2

            emailItem.Subject = "Delayed Task Notification - " & ms.Range("F1").Value
            emailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body><h1 style=""background-color:Red;color:White;text-align:center;""><strong>DELAYED TASK</strong></h1>" & _
                            "<ul>" & _
                            "<li><strong>Product:</strong> " & tbl.ListColumns("Product").DataBodyRange(i).Value & "</li>" & _
                            "<li><strong>Task:</strong> " & tbl.ListColumns("Task").DataBodyRange(i).Value & "</li>" & _
                            "<li><strong>Detail:</strong> " & Replace(Replace(tbl.ListColumns("Task detail").DataBodyRange(i).Value, vbLf & vbLf, " "), Chr(13), "") & "</li>" & _
                            "<li><strong>Due Date:</strong> " & tbl.ListColumns("Due date").DataBodyRange(i).Value & "</li>" & _
                            "</ul></body></html>"

emailItem.send

....
Cell creates problem in table (same excel file):
Feasibility check need to be done (Alt+Enter)
acc.123456XYZ/001.0001-E000 - THEME 2-RELEASE
I tried below alternatives but no progress.

Replace(Replace(tbl.ListColumns("Task detail").DataBodyRange(i).Value, vbLf & vbLf, " "), Chr(13), "")
Replace(tbl.ListColumns("Task detail").DataBodyRange(i).Value, vbLf, " ")
Replace(tbl.ListColumns("Task detail").DataBodyRange(i).Value, Chr(10), " ")
Clean(tbl.ListColumns("Task detail").DataBodyRange(i).Value)


If you want to reproduce the line break in the HTML view you need to replace vbLf with <br>
